# Unable to Wrap Webpage in Electron using BrowserWindow.loadURL()

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to get an app to load a [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/) forum, for example: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/.

I am able to get basic webpages like https://github.com to work, but when I change the line `win.loadURL(https://github.com)` to `win.loadURL(https://ask.fedoraproject.org/)` the header of the electron app changes correctly, but the whole window is white. When I checked in the developer tools it looks like it is not just an issue displaying the webpage, as most of the page is missing.

Is there anything in the code below that I can use to fix the issue?

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')
let win;

function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        win.show()
    })

    win.loadURL('https://ask.fedoraproject.org/')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

// macOS quirks
app.on('closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, checking the console gave me the answer.

Checked the console, and there was an error for missing the module `moment`.

Ran `npm install --save-dev moment` in the project directory, and now it all works :)